# Angular encoding data

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I've got this code

**Javascript**

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '../../php/getMesas.php',

  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.mesas = response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
      $scope.mesas = 'No Response';
  });
```

That is trying to get some table numbers, but when this really works it shows me the parameter name and the value, i need only the value, what can i do to get only the value so not the parameter name?
I'm using PHP as database connector.

**PHP Code**

```
<?php 
include('base.php');
$data = array();
$result = mysql_query('SELECT table_number FROM waiters_assigned ORDER BY id',$connect);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
        $data[] = $row; 
    } 
} else { 
    echo "0 results"; 
}; 
echo json_encode($data);
mysql_close($connect); 
?>
```

The result is this one: `{"table_number":"3"}` what i need is just: `3`

Comment: can you provide an example of the returned data, and what you expect the result to be please. Similarly the PHP code used to generate the response would be lovely

Comment: ok! right. Here's the php code.

<?php
 include('base.php');
 $data = array();
 $result = mysql_query('SELECT table_number FROM waiters_assigned ORDER BY id',$connect);
 if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $data[] = $row;
 }
} else {
 echo "0 results";
};
echo json_encode($data);
mysql_close($connect);
?>

the result is this one: {"table_number":"3"}
what i need is just: 3.

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated; use the `mysqli_` ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please dont use `mysql_query` you should have a look at [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) or at the very least [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), for security and because it is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

As for returning just the number, update your `while` to return the field you desire:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ $data[] = (int)$row['table_number']; }
```

When looking at your PHP i believe you're actually getting `[{"table_number":"3"}]`, as you're `json_encode`ing an array.

The reason updating your PHP is better than updating your Javascript is that you appear to be returning an array of objects currently, when you actually want to return an array of numbers. Doing things the JS way you'll need to cycle through the response, `parseInt` on the strings, and strip the object down to a number. Far easier and more efficient to just send the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

In your php code use `mysqli` or `pdo` extension because `mysql` extension is deprecated.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '../../php/getMesas.php',

  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.mesas = response.data.table_number;//outputs 3
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
      $scope.mesas = 'No Response';
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '../../php/getMesas.php',
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.mesas = response.data ? "" + response.data.table_number : "";
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    $scope.mesas = 'No Response';
});
```